# Will silent notitifcation be displayed like normal notifications even if didReceiveRemoteNotifications is not called by iOS

Tags: ios

- Right now, my iOS app receives normal (non-silent) push notifications.
- iOS device displays notifications as expected.
- Now, I want to convert normal notifications to silent by adding `"content-available=1"` along with all other user visible keys.
- To be able to perform bg tasks on notification trigger

My understanding is iOS may not always call `didReceiveRemoteNotifications` for silent notifications.

My question is would silent notifications will get displayed by iOS (if it contains user visible keys) even if iOS decides not to call `didReceiveRemoteNotifications`

My expectation is silent notifications should work as is like normal notifications with an advantage of didReceiveRemoteNotifications getting called as and when possible (Best Effort)

I don't want to lose normal notification behavior by switching to silent notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31296)

> For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert,
>   sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow
>   this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be
>   throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead
>   of being silent is displayed to the user

So if the keys alert, sound and badge are added then that notification will be displayed like a normal push notification.